# JS regex not ending with

Tags: javascript, regex

I've following regex to match urls:

```
/(https?:\/\/[^"<\s]+[^.<\s"()][-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)/gi
```

Who match both urls:

```
http://example.fr/image.png
http://example.fr/image.pdf
```

This is a specific regex to our application, I want to keep it as it, but just add one functionality.

**Question: I want to ignore urls ending with `.png`.**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, it is possible.

Use a negative lookbehind at the end, and force it to match the entire string:

```
(https?:\/\/[^"<\s]+[^.<\s"()][-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)(?<!\.png)$
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/GEjjiK/2)

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\.png)` is a zero-width match if the current position isn't preceeded by something matching `\.png`.
`$` forces the regex to match the entire line.

Comment: thanks, problem is I can have characters after the url, see https://regex101.com/r/lMCWPP/1

Comment: Then change the `$` into a character set of values definitely not in the URL: https://regex101.com/r/lMCWPP/2

Comment: Thanks, what if I don't want to match the space after the end of the url?